# Django Admin nested inline

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I need a nested django admin inline,
which I can include the date field inlines in an other inline like below.

I have the models below:

```
class Person(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     id_no = models.IntegerField()

class Certificate(models.Model):
     cerfificate_no = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     certificate_date = models.DateField(max_length=100)
     person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
     training = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Training_Date(models.Model):
      date = models.DateField()
      certificate = models.ForeignKey(Certificate)
```

And, the admin below:

```
class CertificateInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Certificate

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     inlines = [CertificateInline,]
admin.site.register(Person,PersonAdmin)
```

But, I need to include the Training_Date model as inline which is part of Certificate admin inline.

Any idea?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't have a second level of inlines in the default Django admin.

The Django admin is just a normal Django application, so nothing prevents you from implementing a second level of nested forms, but IMHO it would be a kind of convoluted design to implement. Perhaps that is why there is no provision for it.

Comment: I am faced with a similar scenario. I think I am going to just override the inline template and add some links to the second level.

Answer (score 48):

There has been some movement in https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9025 recently, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

One common way around this is to link to an admin between first and second (or second and third) level by having both a `ModelAdmin` and an Inline for the same model:

Give `Certificate` a `ModelAdmin` with `TrainingDate` as an inline. Set `show_change_link = True` for `CertificateInline` so you can click on an inline to go to its `ModelAdmin` change form.

admin.py:

```
# Certificate change form has training dates as inline

class TrainingDateInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = TrainingDate

class CertificateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TrainingDateInline,]
admin.site.register(Certificate ,CertificateAdmin)

# Person has Certificates inline but rather
# than nesting inlines (not possible), shows a link to
# its own ModelAdmin's change form, for accessing TrainingDates:

class CertificateLinkInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Certificate
    # Whichever fields you want: (I usually use only a couple
    # needed to identify the entry)
    fields = ('cerfificate_no', 'certificate_date')
    # Django 1.8 introduced this, no need to make your own link
    show_change_link = True

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CertificateLinkInline,]
admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. I want to point out that you can put the `changeform_link` in the `CertificateLinkInline`. That might be a better place because it's django-admin specific. Note that when you do this you should use `instance.id` instead of `self.id` to get to the instance of the model. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Comment: If the changeform_link method produces an exception then django will eat it and continue, leaving the field blank. I was never able to find where django puts the traceback or if it does anything with it at all.  I suggest wrapping it in a try/except to make sure the exception gets logged somewhere.  To simplify, it may be useful to create a decorator handle all of this.

Comment: Looks like on Django 2+ you can just add `show_change_link = True` to your admin.TabularInline class and I think as long as you have a regular admin.ModelAdmin for it also, it will show a “change” link in the inline.

Comment: Though using `show_change_link = True` is much simpler.

Comment: @MrColes @chaulap `show_change_link` was introduced by Django 1.8, released April 1, 2015. Over a year after my answer, but yes, that's been the one-liner equivalent since then. :)

Comment: @DannyW.Adair Excelent solution +1! Would be great for people if you update your answer with `show_change_link = True`, even with people already noticing it on the comments, because visitors and newcomers might not check the comments. Of course, you don't *have* to do it, but would be very nice of you.

Comment: @RamonK. Done - I've updated the solution (somehow my comment from 2 days ago about this disappeared)

Comment: I didn't knew about `show_change_link = True`! That's awesome!

Answer (score 32):

More universal solution

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.urls import reverse

class EditLinkToInlineObject(object):
    def edit_link(self, instance):
        url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (
            instance._meta.app_label,  instance._meta.model_name),  args=[instance.pk] )
        if instance.pk:
            return mark_safe(u'<a href="{u}">edit</a>'.format(u=url))
        else:
            return ''

class MyModelInline(EditLinkToInlineObject, admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyModel
    readonly_fields = ('edit_link', )

class MySecondModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MyModelInline, )

admin.site.register(MyModel)
admin.site.register(MySecondModel, MySecondModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Simple and flexible.  +1

Comment: A very similar solution has been described in more detail in this article: https://djangotricks.blogspot.com/2016/12/django-administration-inlines-for-inlines.html

Answer (score 20):

```
pip install django-nested-inline
```

This package should do what you need.

Comment: **django-nested-inline** isn't (yet?) supported on latest django releases.

But you could consider using https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin that is almost the same.

Comment: @vmonteco could you give me a link to the doc, where described how to use it without packages?

Comment: @OleksandrDashkov http://django-nested-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, on the top of the github page. But probably still have to install the package anyway.

Comment: Word of warning, I started using django-nested-inline and have run into multiple bugs that are time consuming to figure out. You may want to evaluate other options before deciding on which module to use.

Comment: @pspahn did you find any reasonable alternative to this

Answer (score 6):

A more up-to-date solution (february 2021) is to use the **show_change_link** config variable: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.show_change_link

This does exactly the same as the EditLinkToInlineObject proposed in solutions above, but is less code and is probably well tested by Django Developers

You would just have to define `show_change_link=True` in each one of your inlines

Answer (score 5):

Nested inlines are provided at:
https://github.com/BertrandBordage/django-super-inlines/

```
pip install django-super-inlines
```

Comment: I tried it. It does not allow me to add or delete some of the inlines and forces me to make 3 new child objects. It's not usable at this stage  of development.

Answer (score 5):

Use [**django-nested-admin**](https://django-nested-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is the best package to do nested inlines.

First, install **"django-nested-admin"**:

```
pip install django-nested-admin
```

Then, add **"nested_admin"** to **"INSTALLED_APPS"** in **"settings.py"**:

```py
# "settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    "nested_admin", # Here
)
```

Then, add **"path('_nested_ad..."** to **"urlpatterns"** in **"urls.py"**:

```py
# "urls.py"

from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('_nested_admin/', include('nested_admin.urls')), # Here
]
```

Finally, extend **"NestedTabularInline"** with **"Training_DateInline()" and "CertificateInline()" classes** and extend **"NestedModelAdmin"** with **"PersonAdmin()" class** in **"admin.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from .models import Training_Date, Certificate, Person
from nested_admin import NestedTabularInline, NestedModelAdmin

class Training_DateInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = Training_Date

class CertificateInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = Certificate
    inlines = [Training_DateInline]

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CertificateInline]
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the solution provided by @bigzbig (thank you).

I also wanted to go back to the first list page once changes had been saved so added:

```
class MyModelInline(EditLinkToInlineObject, admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyModel
    readonly_fields = ('edit_link', )

    def response_post_save_change(self, request, obj):
        my_second_model_id = MyModel.objects.get(pk=obj.pk).my_second_model_id
        return redirect("/admin/mysite/mysecondmodel/%s/change/" % (my_second_model_id))
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet! I just wanted to add that this only worked for me after including the post_save_change function inside MyModelAdmin.