# Adding another select field to django admin interface

Tags: django, foreign-keys, modelform, limit-choices-to

So in one app i have four models. From first to last they are name 'brand', 'mark', 'type', 'engine'.

Mark has a foreign key to brand, type has a foreign key to mark, and engine has one to type.

In the admin interface when I add a mark I get a dropdown list to choose from all the Brands. When I add a type, I get a dropdown list to choose from all the Marks.

What I want: when I am adding a Type, I want to also be able to choose the Brand from a dropdown list, and that choice, to filter the next dropdown from Marks.

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import a_brand, b_mark, c_type, d_engine
from .forms import TypeModelAdminForm

## these are my models

```
from django.db import models

class a_brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    brand_logo = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='C:/Users/Robert/Desktop/carsbook/static/catalog/brandslogos'
        )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['brand_name']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name

class b_mark(models.Model):
    mark_brand = models.ForeignKey(a_brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mark_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    mark_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='C:/Users/Robert/Desktop/carsbook/static/catalog/marksimages', 
        default='C:/Users/Robert/Desktop/carsbook/static/default/default.jpg'
        )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("mark_brand", "mark_name")
        ordering = ['mark_brand', 'mark_name']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.mark_name

class c_type(models.Model):
    type_mark = models.ForeignKey(b_mark, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    type_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='C:/Users/Robert/Desktop/carsbook/static/catalog/typesimages', 
        default='C:/Users/Robert/Desktop/carsbook/static/default/default.jpg'
        )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("type_mark", "type_name")
        ordering = ['type_mark', 'type_name']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.type_name

class d_engine(models.Model):
    engine_type = models.ForeignKey(c_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    engine_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("engine_type", "engine_name")
        ordering = ['engine_type', 'engine_name']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.engine_name
```

## this is what I have in my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import a_brand, b_mark, c_type, d_engine
from .forms import TypeModelAdminForm

class b_markModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["brand", "__str__"]
    search_fields = ["mark_brand__brand_name", "mark_name"]
    list_display_links = ["__str__"]
    class Meta:
        model = b_mark
    def brand(self, instance):
        return instance.mark_brand

class c_typeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TypeModelAdminForm
    list_display = ["brand", "type_mark", "__str__"]
    search_fields = ["type_name", "type_mark__mark_name", "type_mark__mark_brand__brand_name"]
    list_display_links = ["__str__"]
    class Meta:
        model = c_type
    def brand(self, instance):
        return instance.type_mark.mark_brand
    def mark(self, instance):
        return instance.type_mark

class d_engineModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["brand", "mark", "type", "__str__"]
    search_fields = [
        "engine_name", 
        "engine_type__type_name", 
        "engine_type__type_mark__mark_name", 
        "engine_type__type_mark__mark_brand__brand_name"
        ]
    list_display_links = ["__str__"]
    class Meta:
        model = d_engine
    def brand(self, instance):
        return instance.engine_type.type_mark.mark_brand
    def mark(self, instance):
        return instance.engine_type.type_mark
    def type(self, instance):
        return instance.engine_type

admin.site.register(a_brand)
admin.site.register(b_mark, b_markModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(c_type, c_typeModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(d_engine, d_engineModelAdmin)
```

When I am in my admin site, and am adding an c_type or d_engine model, to be able not only to choose the foreign key of the "upper" model, but instead filter them based on brand, then mark, then engine.

So for example, when I am adding en d_engine, I have to choose a foreignkey from all the types, from all the marks, from all the brands. Instead I want to first somehow choose the brand first, the chosen brand to filter, the next drowdown list of marks, then the selected mark, to filter the types, and only then I chose the c_type.

It is kind of confusing to explain.

Comment: Please add some codes, what you trying out?

Comment: there I did add some of the code

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is nested inlines in the admin, which is not a feature of django admin as of yet. Try the solutions from this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308050/django-admin-nested-inline