# Django admin: Inline straight to second-level relationship

Tags: python, django, admin, relationship, inline-formset

I have a three-levels `Invoice` model which I'd like to display on Django's admin area... in a "kind of *special*" way.

Allow me to provide a bit of background:

Each `Invoice` is conformed by several `SubInvoice`(s), and each `SubInvoice` is conformed by several `InvoiceItem`(s), which contain a break down of the `Products` purchased by a customer.

Logically speaking, it'd be something like this (hopefully the ascii art works)

```
+---------- Invoice id=3 -----------+
|       Full total: $100.00         |
|                                   |
|  +----- Sub Invoice id=1 -----+   |
|  |      Subtotal $70          |   |
|  |                            |   |
|  |    Item 1 in SubInv.1      |   |
|  |    Item 2 in SubInv.1      |   |
|  |    Item 3 in SubInv.1      |   |
|  |____________________________|   |
|                                   |
|  +----- Sub Invoice id=2 -----+   |
|  |      Subtotal $30          |   |
|  |                            |   |
|  |    Item 1 in SubInv.2      |   |
|  |    Item 2 in SubInv.2      |   |
|  |____________________________|   |
|                                   |
|___________________________________|
```

The models look more or less (they've been simplified for this question) like:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    full_total = DecimalField(...)
    # has a .sub_invoices RelatedManager through a backref from SubInvoice

class SubInvoice(models.Model):
    sub_total = DecimalField(...)
    invoice = ForeignKey('server.Invoice', related_name='sub_invoices')
    # has an .items RelatedManager through a backref from InvoiceItem

class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    sub_invoice = ForeignKey('server.SubInvoice', related_name='items')
    product = ForeignKey('server.Product', related_name='+')
    quantity = PositiveIntegerField(...)
    price = DecimalField(...)
```

Now, I am aware that nesting two levels of relationships in Django Admin is very complex, and I'm not trying to nest the `InvoiceItem` into the `SubInvoice` and nest that one into the `Invoice`. That'd be great, but I'm ready to give that up due to the difficulties of nested inlines. **No:** what I'd like to to do is showing the `Invoice` and, as an `inline`, its `Items`, *"jumping"* through `Invoice.sub_invoices__items`. I don't really care that much about the information shown in the `SubInvoice`(s), but I do care about the information in the `Invoice` and in the `InvoiceItems`.

What I mean is that, basically, I would like (or *"I could live with"*, rather) if the `Invoice` admin view looked like the following:

```
+---------- Invoice id=3 -----------+
|       Full total: $100.00         |
|                                   |
|  +----------------------------+   |
|  |                            |   |
|  |    Item 1 in SubInv.1      |   |
|  |    Item 2 in SubInv.1      |   |
|  |    Item 3 in SubInv.1      |   |
|  |    Item 1 in SubInv.2      |   |
|  |    Item 2 in SubInv.2      |   |
|  |____________________________|   |
|                                   |
|___________________________________|
```

(*`InvoiceItems`* as an inline of the *`Invoice`*(s) without showing any information about the *`SubInvoices`* in it)

I've tried the following in the `admin.py`:

```
class InvoiceItemInline(admin.StackedInline):
    fk_name = 'sub_invoice__invoice'
    model = InvoiceItem

class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (InvoiceItemInline,)
```

But that gives me an error:

`<class 'server.admin.invoices.InvoiceItemInline'>: (admin.E202) 'server.InvoiceItem' has no field named 'sub_invoice__invoice'.`

I've also tried directly this:

```
class InvoiceItemInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = InvoiceItem

class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (InvoiceItemInline,)
```

But then (this one I was expecting) produces this error:

`<class 'server.admin.invoices.InvoiceItemInline'>: (admin.E202) 'server.InvoiceItem' has no ForeignKey to 'server.Invoice'.`

Is there any way of achieving this? Thank you in advance.

**PS:**

As of now, I have a "patched" solution which seems to be the canonical way:

- Register the `Invoice` model.
- Register an [`admin.ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) *inline* for the `SubInvoice` (this inline will be "inlined" into the `Invoice`'s ModelAdmin).
- Also register the `SubInvoice` in the admin, so we can calculate a link to its admin view.
- Add an *inline* view of the `InvoiceItems` to the aforementioned `SubInvoice`'s view.
- Add a link to the admin view of the `SubInvoice`(s) in the `Invoice`

Pretty much what is described in this other [S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14328715/289011).

But the problem with this approach is that it won't let me see the `Invoice` and its `InvoiceItems`at a glance (I see the invoice, with sub_invoices in it, and then within the sub_invoices inlines, there's a link to the InvoiceItems which I have to click on in order to see the items). It'd be great if I could get rid of the need for that link.

This is what I have now, basically:

```
+---------- Invoice id=3 -----------+
|       Full total: $100.00         |
|                                   |
|  +----- Sub Invoice id=1 -----+   |       +--- Sub Invoice id=1 ---+
|  |      Subtotal $70          |   |       |   Item 1 in SubInv.1   |
|  |                            |   |       |   Item 2 in SubInv.1   |
|  |    <a>Click for items ==============>  |   Item 3 in SubInv.1   |
|  |____________________________|   |       |________________________|
|                                   |
|  +----- Sub Invoice id=2 -----+   |
|  |      Subtotal $30          |   |       +--- Sub Invoice id=2 ---+
|  |                            |   |       |   Item 1 in SubInv.2   |
|  |    <a>Click for items ==============>  |   Item 2 in SubInv.2   |
|  |____________________________|   |       |________________________|
|                                   |
|___________________________________|
```

Comment: You can try django-nested-admin (https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin), which provides support for two-level inlines

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem could be solved using the `ManyToManyField` + `through`. (This is an example)

```
#models.py
class Invoice(models.Model):
    full_total = DecimalField(...)
    # has a .sub_invoices RelatedManager through a backref from SubInvoice

class SubInvoice(models.Model):
    sub_total = DecimalField(...)
    invoice = ManyToManyField(
        'server.Invoice',
        through='server.InvoiceItem',
        through_fields=('sub_invoice', 'invoice'))
    # has an .items RelatedManager through a backref from InvoiceItem

class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    sub_invoice = ForeignKey('server.SubInvoice')
    invoice = ForeignKey('server.Invoice')
    product = ForeignKey('server.Product', related_name='+')
    quantity = PositiveIntegerField(...)
    price = DecimalField(...)

#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import InvoiceItem, Invoice, SubInvoice


class InvoiceItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = InvoiceItem
    extra = 1


class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (InvoiceItemInline,)


admin.site.register(Invoice, InvoiceAdmin)
admin.site.register(SubInvoice, InvoiceAdmin)
```

I would recommend working with classes for this one in your `views.py` and use `inlineformset_factory` in your `forms.py` for this.
Using `jquery-formset` library in your frontend as well, as this looks pretty neat together.

NOTE:
You can also use `on_delete=models.CASCADE` if you want in the `InvoiceItem` on the foreignkeys, so if one of those items is deleted, then the InvoiceItem will be deleted too, or `models.SET_NULL`, whichever you prefer.

Hope this might help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to keep the `InvoiceItem` normalized (just with the `sub_invoice` FK, and not having to add the `invoice` also)

Comment: The `Invoice` isn't visible when you click on `Invoice` in the admin view, rather you will see all the `SubInvoices` with the `InvoiceItems` linked to the `Invoice` and in the `SubInvoice` you will see which `Invoice` and `InvoiceItem` it's linked to. Maybe you could do a test with this to see the results of what I mean? Because now you don't have to register the `InvoiceItem` in your `admin.py` to be able to see it. I would love to figure your problem out as I'm very much so interested in this :)

Comment: Sorry: I was actually talking about the models: In your code, the `InvoiceItem` must have two foreign keys: One to `SubInvoice` and another one to `Invoice`, which de-normalizes the tables since `InvoiceItem.invoice` is "redundant" (redundant in the sense that the `invoice` the `InvoiceItem` belongs to is **also** reachable through `InvoiceItem --> sub_invoice --> invoice` so in theory, I could force an InvoiceItem to belong to a `subinvoice` that doesn't actually belong to the same `invoice`, right? (maybe I'm looking at this wrong, though)

Comment: My concern (to further clarify the comment above) is: What happens if I stick the wrong value (let's say I put a... dunno... `invoice_id=42`) in `InvoiceItem.invoice` and then I have a situation in which, following the path `InvoiceItem --> sub_invoice --> invoice` I reach the `invoice` with ID 3, but following the path `InvoiceItem --> invoice`, I reach the `invoice` with ID 42

Comment: In the example I gave you the `SubInvoice` has `full_total`, `product`, `quantity` and `price`. The `Invoice` has  `sub_total`, `product`, `quantity` and `price`. In this case the SubInvoice, Invoice and InvoiceItem will all three still have use for each other. In your examples it seems like you mean to use this as well. Like this there also won't be any ID problems. I could post an image of how it looks in the database if you want to?

Comment: Yeah, those fields are used, and your example is fine in that regard: My concern comes because of the presence of the two FK (`.invoice` and `.sub_invoice`) in the `InvoiceItem`. Without `InvoiceItem.invoice`, the question _What `Invoice` does this `InvoiceItem` belongs to?_ can uniquely be answered through `InvoiceItem.sub_invoice.invoice` But if I add the `InvoiceItem.invoice` FK, now I can (potentially) have 2 paths to reach the item's `invoice`: One, through `InvoiceItem.sub_invoice.invoice` and another one through `InvoiceItem.invoice`, no? If so, it feels it lead to potential bugs?

Comment: You can call to `InvoiceItem.invoice` and `SubInvoice.through.invoice` in this case, as for *what* `Invoice` the `InvoiceItem` belongs to is up to you which `Invoice` you want it to belong to.

Comment: You can however also have the `ManyToManyField` in the `InvoiceItem` refering to `SubInvoice` going through `Invoice` which will create a whole other scenario, like I said the code I wrote is just an example of how you can use a `ManyToManyField`, which I think can also do the thing that you want to establish.