# Django Dynamic Nested Formsets

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have 3 models Clinic, Doctor, DoctorHours
I want to create a dynamic form which will allow me to create those instances in one form
something like this:

-ClinicForm

--add_doctor_button

--DoctorForm

```
----add_doctor_hours_button

----DoctorHoursForm

----DoctorHoursForm
```

--DoctorForm

```
----add_doctor_hours_button

----DoctorHoursForm

----DoctorHoursForm

----DoctorHoursForm
```

Please help

My best try:

view:

```
class CreatePracticeFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'admin/practices/create_form.html'
    form_class = PracticeCreateForm
    success_url = '/admin/emr/practice/'

    def form_valid(self, form):

        print(self.request.POST)

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

forms:

```
class DoctorWorkingHoursForm(forms.Form):

    week_day = forms.ChoiceField(choices=DoctorWorkingHours.WeekDay.choices)
    start_time = forms.TimeField(required=True)
    end_time = forms.TimeField()


DoctorWorkingHoursFormSet = forms.formset_factory(DoctorWorkingHoursForm, extra=0)


class DoctorCreateForm(forms.Form):

    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    npi = forms.EmailField()
    specialty = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Speciality.objects.all())
    credentials = forms.CharField()
    hours = DoctorWorkingHoursFormSet()

DoctorCreateFormSet = forms.formset_factory(DoctorCreateForm, extra=0)

class PracticeCreateForm(forms.Form):

    name = forms.CharField()
    type = forms.CharField()
    primary_contact_name = forms.CharField()
    ehr = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=EHR.objects.all())
    scheduling_extension = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SchedulingExtension.objects.all())
    primary_visit_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=VisitType.objects.all())
    secondary_visit_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=VisitType.objects.all())
    doctors = DoctorCreateFormSet()

DoctorCreateFormSet = forms.formset_factory(DoctorCreateForm, extra=0, formset=BaseDoctorCreateFormset)
```

Here what I get is the forms in template where I can dynamically add DoctorForm and HourForm with jQuery and get that data in the view

but how to validate and assemble this data into objects it is the big question

Comment: Please provide some code or an initial attempt. Otherwise this answer is too broad and open ended for the SO format. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DanielMorell added best try

Comment: Is this meant to be used in the Django admin?

Comment: @DanielMorell yes, separate view in admin

Comment: Have you thought about using a `TabularInline` or `StackedInline`, docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects. Or would you need a more custom workflow?

Comment: and I will be able to create DoctorHours (dynamically) inside the Doctor TabularInline on the Practice change page? @DanielMorell

Comment: Maybe. I don't know about nested inlines. But you could read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308050/django-admin-nested-inline

Comment: if possible I'd prefer not to depend on 3rd party packages @DanielMorell

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example of what you could do. It is not exactly nested. But it will provide most of the functionality you are looking for.

```py
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Clinic, Doctor, DoctorHours


class DoctorHoursInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = DoctorHours


@admin.register(Doctor)
class DoctorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # stuff
    inlines = [DoctorHoursInline,]
    # more stuff


class DoctorInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Doctor

    # This will show a link to edit the Doctor model
    # in the Doctor table of the Clinic change form.
    show_change_link = True 


@admin.register(Clinic)
class ClinicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # stuff
    inlines = [DoctorInline,]
    # more stuff
```

You may of course want to swap out the forms on each of these `ModelAdmin` and `TabularInline` classes.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: 2 classes ClinicAdmin is intended ?

Comment: Oops! good catch!

Comment: hmmm
I just see the TabularInline or StackedInline of the Doctors (which is 1st phase of what needed ) in the Clinic change view but no ability to edit hours from there

Comment: There should be a link in the `DoctorInline` to edit the hours. You may need to save the Clinic before the link will be available. I know this is not the cleanest, but it is the best that is available without 3rd party code or JS.

Comment: yeah, that is why I was drafting the separate admin view with form with formset inside with formset inside
anyway thank u for help and your time!

Comment: If you need one form for creating and one for editing you can override the admin class `get_form` method. That keeps you from needing to create a separate view.